Contract::fail Error in FeynCalc When Using Calc[FullSimplify[Y1]] /. momentumRules
I’m working on a quantum field theory calculation in Mathematica using FeynCalc, and I’m running into the following error:
Contract::fail: Error! Contract has encountered a fatal problem and must abort the computation. The problem reads: Something went wrong during prepareProductContractions.

The error occurs when executing this line in my code:
Calc[FullSimplify[Y1]] /. momentumRules

Here’s the relevant portion of my code:
(* Definitions for expressions *)
expr1 = GS[p2] . GA[\[Nu]] . (a - b GA[5]) . (GS[p1] - GS[p3]);
expr2 = GA[\[Mu]] . (a - b GA[5]) . GS[p1] . GA[\[Rho]] . (a - b GA[5]);
expr3 = (GS[p1] - GS[p3]) . GA[\[Sigma]] . (a - b GA[5]);

(* Trace calculation *)
T1 = FullSimplify[TR[expr1 . expr2 . expr3]];

(* Additional expressions *)
expr4 = -MT[\[Mu], \[Rho]] + Pair[Momentum[FV[p3, \[Mu]]], Momentum[FV[p3, \[Rho]]]]/MV^2;
expr5 = -MT[\[Nu], \[Sigma]] +Pair[Momentum[FV[p1 + p2 - p3, \[Nu]]], Momentum[FV[p1 + p2 - p3, \[Sigma]]]]/MV^2;

(* Final combination *)
Y1 = T1 expr4 expr5;

(* Momentum rules for simplification *)
momentumRules = {
    Pair[Momentum[p1], Momentum[p1]] -> 0,
    Pair[Momentum[p2], Momentum[p2]] -> 0,
    Pair[Momentum[p3], Momentum[p3]] -> MV^2
};

(* Problematic line *)
Calc[FullSimplify[Y1]] /. momentumRules

I have tried using Calc in the line Y1 = T1 expr4 expr5; and I get the same error, but if I use in the line T1 = FullSimplify[TR[expr1 . expr2 . expr3]]; there are no issues.
I applied momentumRules to FullSimplify[Y1] before passing it to Calc, but the error still occurs.
    simplifiedY1 = FullSimplify[Y1] /. momentumRules;
Calc[simplifiedY1]

The substitutions with momentumRules also seem fine when applied to simpler expressions.
My Mathematica version is 14.1 and FeynCalc version is 10.1.0.

The syntax of expr4 and expr5 are not correct. Please look up on how to input 4-vectors with open indices in the package.

If I try FV[p3, [Mu]] I get the same error
